# Passing the values from one php page to another where ajax request is been used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page say `1.php` where in i am storing a variable to input field text.

`Name:abc`

`Done.`

When i click done button the name `abc` is passed to another page say `2.php` using ajax request.

In `2.php` i am storing the value `abc` in session.

Now what actually i need is when page `1.php` loads i need the value `abc` to be stored in a php variable.

Only when the value `abc` is been typed and clicked on done the value should be stored in php variable.So that i can use the variable for calling classes.

**Sample Code: 1.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION["abc"]))
{
   $PhoneNumber=$_SESSION["abc"];
   unset($_SESSION["abc"]);
}  
<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalue()
{
   var newreq=createRequest();
   var url=("1.php?abc="+abc);
   .....
   ....
}
</script>
```

**2.php**

```
unset($_SESSION["abc"]);
$_SESSION["abc"]=$abc;
```

Now i need to store `abc` in `$abc` in `1.php`.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not sending it via GET?

Answer (score 0):

$PhoneNumber php variable should have the value of abc if you have already sent the ajax request to store it in SESSION. But if you need to use that value in client side you need to send the value to the browser because the variable is still in server. 
Use directly in javascript:

```
var url=("1.php?abc="+<?=$PhoneNumber?>);
```

Or use anywhere accessing the hidden filed:

```
<input type="hidden" id="abcVal" value="<?=$PhoneNumber?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION["abc"]))
{
   $PhoneNumber=$_SESSION["abc"];
   unset($_SESSION["abc"]);
}  
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalue()
{
   var newreq=createRequest();
   var url=("1.php?abc="+"<?=$PhoneNumber?>");
   .....
   ....
}
</script>
```

2.php

```
unset($_SESSION["abc"]);
$_SESSION["abc"]=$_GET['abc'];
```